# How to style all-caps mainframe text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to format all-caps mainframe text using jQuery and CSS so they're more legible.

So, it should take a block of text like this..

```
THESE ARE MY FAVORITE FRUITS. [BANANA] [APPLE] [ORANGE]
```

and turn it into something like this, by converting open and closed brackets into HTML tag.

> These are my favorite fruits.
>  Banana
>  Apple
>  Orange

This was my painful attempt.

```
<style> 
  .blah {text-transform:capitalize; }    
</style>
<div>THESE ARE MY FAVORITE FRUITS. [BANANA] [APPLE] [ORANGE] </div>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div:contains('[')").replaceWith("<p class='blah'>");
        $("div:contains(']')").replaceWith("</p>"); 
    }); 
</script>
```

but then I realized the selector was targeting the "div" tag, and not the "[".

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytBP7/1/ ?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make myself clear...  It looks like many solutions are use regex to replace brackets with <BR>, which is awesome.  But for formatting flexibility, but it needs to convert open&close brackets into <p> </p> tags.

Comment: using `<br /` was for demo purpose only... you can use a `<p>` tag just like the same... see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.blah').html(function(i,text){
        return text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, '<p>$1</p>')
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ytBP7/)

Comment: thank you Arun, this worked.  Thanks everyone, learned a lot from you guys!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are targetting the div, so now you just need to get the div's text, and replace the elements with your replacements, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div:contains('[')").each(function() {
          var text = $(this).text();
          text = text.split('[').join("<p class='blah'>").split(']').join("</p>");
          $(this).text(text);
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, but it's returning syntax error for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.blah').html($('.blah').html().replace(/[/g,"<br>").replace(/]/g,""));
});
```

Assumes your original text block would have .blah class applied.

Although, it might be better to wrap each item in a container (span with a classname), grab all containers, and run them through an .each() function that makes changes to each one.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="blah">tHESE ARE MY FAVORITE FRUITS. [BANANA] [APPLE] [ORANGE]</div>

<style> 
  .blah {text-transform:capitalize; }    
</style> 

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.blah').html(function (i, text) {
            return text.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, '<br />$1').toLowerCase();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/krishanudey/amtz4/1/)